# ah_auctioneer_pda. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error A seeds constraint was violated. even the though the pda address is correct

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm getting

```
logs: [
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Sell',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: ah_auctioneer_pda. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.',
    'Program log: Left:',
    'Program log: HwnNUbBJ851W2y3DRcbP6BTj4kcbms6b1iMigkGxVyao',
    'Program log: Right:',
    'Program log: BxmzWcikLxWocve3z1sHPERbJj2wKCZbdnRXTuWFSGQF',
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh consumed 30549 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh failed: custom program error: 0x7d6'
  ]
```

while trying to list through auctionner, But the ah_pda_address is correct
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Was running into a similar issue earlier. How are you executing this IX (via Rust or TS?). Ended up resolving it as I wasn't passing in the required accounts to be hashed correctly.

What are the required seeds for the PDA?

Comment: It got automatically fixed when i upgraded js sdk to 0.2.0

Comment: Hey @AbhishekFaliya I've been using your excellent auctioneer lib to build out a cli and fixing a lot of the same bugs. Feel free to reference and open any pull requests as you see fit https://github.com/h4rkl/metaplex-auctioneer-cli